# How to Disable and Enable the URL ecrypting in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have all my URLs updated to links as below,

```js
%%[
    SET @MyURL = "http://Www.example.com"
]%%
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@MyURL)=%%">Click here</a>
```

For a custom Integration, I need some URLs to be encrypted as below.
[image]
And some URLs should NOT be as below. [without encrypted] 
http://www.example.com

As per I know all the links within the emails will be encrypted! Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have [Link Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_link_tracking.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) in mind. If you track clicks on the links in your email, they all will be redirected to capture the click info, which means that they will go through `http://cl.exct.net/`. The original URL will be replaced with a new one that routes to Marketing Cloud click processors.

In order to disable tracking and have the links go straight to the URL you provided, use the Concat AMPscript function, like in this example from the documentation:

```
%%[
var @URL
Set @URL = "<a href='http://google.com'>Google 1</a>"
]%%

<br>
%%=v(@url)=%%
<br>
```

Bare in mind, that this will preserve the original URL, but you won't be able to track clicks on this URL inside Marketing Cloud. You can still track them in Google Analytics or a similar tool, if you add utm parameters to the link.

Read more here: [Stop a link from being tracked in a Marketing Cloud email](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314602&language=en_US&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1)

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for 